# Python CSV: IndexError: List Index out of range

Tags: python, csv

I have very weird problem in working with csv. My code is :

```
        with open('CFD.csv', 'rt') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
            for row in reader:
                if cfd_number == row[0]:
                    cfd_checked_before = "Yes"
```

This code is working in Mac but in windows, I get the following error:

```
IndexError: List Index out of range
```

Comment: Does your CSV have an empty line? Try `print(row)` before the test and see what you get.

Comment: Yes, There are some empty line in csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its common to have empty lines in csv files, especially at the end of the file. If you want your code to accept this common error, just check the row list before use.

```
with open('CFD.csv', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if row:
            if cfd_number == row[0]:
                cfd_checked_before = "Yes"
```

You can also use `filter` for the same task. When its first parameter is None, it removes "falsey" things like empty lists:

```
with open('CFD.csv', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in filter(None, reader):
        if cfd_number == row[0]:
            cfd_checked_before = "Yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are maybe some possible cases there...

- Maybe you are opening a csv file in Windows not even alike as the csv file you are using in Mac
- Maybe the problem there is in the line **row[0]**
- Maybe your csv file does not contains any comma delimiter or some rows there has an empty line as stated.

try printing the **row** variable or even the **reader** variable

Comment: Interesting observations, but these should be in the question's comment section. Answers are for things that really do answer the question.

Comment: got it thanks! Im a new contributor I will try it next time..

Comment: Yes there are some empty file in csv file